# PHP: Remplazar un número consecutivo que ha sido eliminado

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un campo en una tabla con números correlativos

| num | nom |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-0001 | -- |
| 2022-0002 | -- |
| 2022-0003 | -- |
| 2022-0004 | -- |
| **numero eliminado** | -- |
| 2022-0006 | -- |
| 2022-0007 | -- |

En laravel obtego estos números

```
$numbers= Table::all(); //obtengo los numeros
// creo una lista
$lista = [];
        
        foreach($numbers as $number) 
        {
           // separo el año de los numeros consecutivos
            $porciones = explode("-", $number->num;);
           // agrego los números enteros a la lista
           // con el fin de poder hacer operaciones matematicas que me ayuden
            array_push($lista,(int)$porciones[1]); 
        };
  //obtengo la lista de enteros
   $lista;
 //output $lista [1,2,3,4,6,7]
```

Ahora como podría comprobar en mi lista un número correlativo faltante(esto al ser eliminado de la bd) como lo es el 5.

Una vez se haya comprobado que el número no está en la lista, se pueda utilizar el número faltante al momento de insertar el siguente elemento.

any idea pls...

Comment: Si, asi es.. puesto que se insertan con un contador

Comment: A la hora de borrar un número, ¿sería correcto renumerar todos los insertados mayor a este? o a lo mejor ¿sería prudente guardar en otra tabla este número para luego se utilizado? Te pregunto porque quizas hoy son pocos números, pero mañana pueden ser millones y recorrer la lista no va a ser muy performante que digamos...

Comment: asi es justo me comentan, que debería salvar el numero eliminado en una tabla nueva

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'num' in where clause is ambiguou, eso me salió @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

A nivel base de datos no hay forma de que la tabla sepa que le hacen falta datos, es decir, es únicamente un almacén de información

Lo que quieres hacer es parte de la "Limpieza de información" que está dentro de tu base de datos, es decir, tienes que validar que la información que está en tu base de datos sea correcta

Algunas acciones dentro de esta "Limpieza de información" son:

1. Comprobar si hay datos faltantes
2. Comprobar si hay datos con valores fuera de rango
3. Comprobar si hay datos sobrantes

Entre otras...

Por ejemplo, en este caso tu sabes que los valores de la columna `num` tienen que incrementar de 1 en 1 puedes utilizar eso como regla para validar tu información

Podrías hacer un `foreach` que vaya desde el valor mínimo al máximo y revisar que cada uno de los valores exista

Por ejemplo (En este caso solo utilizando los datos de tu tabla ejemplo):

```
foreach (range(0, 7) as $numero) {
    // validación de $numero
}
```

Laravel tiene una función para validar si alguna entrada existe

```
exists:tabla,columna
```

Puedes leer más sobre validación en laravel [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exists)

Lo que puedes hacer es hacer el `foreach` antes mencionado en tu validación y buscar cada valor dentro de tu tabla

```
foreach (range(0, 7) as $numero) {
    $numero => 'exists:NombreDeTuTabla,num'
}
```

Lo que no explicas en tu pregunta es si solo tienes que validar que la información esté completa o si debes agregar los elementos faltantes o si por alguna razón alguien elimina uno entonces renumerar todas las demás filas y "recorrer" los datos para que no haya elementos faltantes

**Edición:**

Otra forma más eficaz de hacerlo en lugar de recorrer uno por uno es obtener todos los valores de `num` y crear un arreglo que vaya del valor mínimo al máximo que esperas en tu tabla y comparar los arreglos con `array_diff()`

```
$numeros = Table::all()->pluck('num')->toArray(); //Esto te va a devolver únicamente num en forma de arreglo
$rango_total = range(1, max($numeros)); //Esto crea el rango esperado de valores desde 1 hasta el valor máximo encontrado en $numeros
$valores_faltantes= array_diff($rango_total, $numeros);
```

De esta forma obtienes todos los valores faltantes de una sola vez y puedes utilizar el menor de ellos para la nueva entrada a tu base de datos

Comment: Es justo como lo explicas al final, si el usuario va a eliminar un registro.. por lo que dañará la secuencia de números...
El asunto esta en mantener la correlación.

Comment: El proceso puede ser el mismo, utilizar la validación con `exists` al momento de crear una nueva entrada y entonces cuando un valor no exista utilizas ese valor en la nueva entrada

Comment: en el tema de rendimiento, no afectaría esa validación, o convedría crear una nueva tabla para salvar los números, como las otras sugerencias

Comment: @JorgeltRTrujillo, acabo de editar la respuesta, puedes utilizar un `array_dif()` para obtener todos los valores faltantes de una sola vez

Comment: Ok, voy intentar esto para ver si resuelve el probema :)

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

para la query utilizaremos **SUBSTRING_INDEX** aunque tambien puedes utilizar **like '2022-%'** para recuperar todo

query:

```
$year = '2022';
$max = '0010';
$query = "select num from test where (SUBSTRING_INDEX(num,'-',-1) BETWEEN '0001' and '{$max}') and (SUBSTRING_INDEX(num,'-',1) = {$year});";
```

ahora solo debes hacer un for clasico o un foreach y ver los numero que no existen.

te dejo una funcion

```
function nums($arr){
  $max_number = 20; // numero maximo de intentos
  $c=0; // contador
  $range =4; // rango de digitos en este caso 4 .. 0001 a 9999
  $cero = "";  
  // maximo numero de intententos
  while($max_number >= $c){
    $cero = str_pad($c, $range, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if(!in_array("{$cero}", $arr[$c] ))
       return $cero
    $c++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Si, max number es el numero maximo y range es  para asignar ceros delante porque puedes querer 1000 numeros pero con un rango de 5 que seria 01000

Comment: Gracias por compartir tu idea, aprendi mucho con esto :)